# :: in strings in Python

Tags: python

I've been learning Python and I must say I loved it. But as a new learners I am having some other problems as well:

Could you guys tell me whether it is a feature of Python or the library of itself.

I am checking how to connect to sqllite database and I came up with this article and there is a code sample over there as such below:

```
>>> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
>>> connection = sqlite.connect('test.db')
>>> memoryConnection = sqlite.connect(':memory:')
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
```

When he wrote memory as string, he put two `:` (colon) as well and I am wondering whether it is peculiar to library instead of Python itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `':memory:'` string is entirely database dependent. As explained in the [documentation for `sqlite`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect):

> You can use `":memory:"` to open a database connection to a database that resides in RAM instead of on disk.

As far as the Python language is concerned, `':memory:'` is just a string like any other.

Answer (score 2):

from: http://nullege.com/codes/search/pysqlite2.dbapi2.connect

> You can use ":memory:" to open a database connection to a database
>   that resides in RAM instead of on disk.

the colon are not special for python

Answer (score 1):

It's peculiar to the SQLite connection String, nothing to do with Python.